# java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException in WIldfly 10

Tags: maven, wildfly, cdi, wildfly-10, jboss-weld

I get this error when I try to start WAR package in Wildfly 10 with several dependencies:

```
15:44:52,564 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Web_package.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Web_package.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
    Exception 0 :
    javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessManagedBeanImpl.fire(ProcessManagedBeanImpl.java:31)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessBean(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:227)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploySpecialized(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:109)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deploySpecialized(BeanDeployment.java:261)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:410)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiExtension.collect(CdiExtension.java:172)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
        at javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral.getTypeParameter(TypeLiteral.java:103)
        at javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral.getType(TypeLiteral.java:66)
        at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.<clinit>(CdiUtils.java:84)
        ... 29 more

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
```

This is my POM file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to change CDI dependency but the result is the same. Can you give me some advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: If you're deploying to an app server, you should make sure `weld` and `JSF`  dependencies are provided.  Does the error go away when you fix that?

Comment: You should use provided scope for Java EE dependencies ike weld or JSF